# english to metric conversion with cubes

Tags: unit-of-measure

How do you convert $ft^3$ to $cm^3$? I can find an exact relationship online, but what if I just knew how many $m$ are in a $lb$ or something like that?

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. "How many m are in a lb"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** $1 ft = 12\text{in}$, $1\text{in} = 2.54 \text{cm}$. So $1 ft^3 = 12^3 \text{in}^3 = 1,728 \text{in}^3 = 1,728 \cdot 2.54^3 \text{cm}^3 = 28,316.85 \text{cm}^3$